# What is a good way to manage PL/pgSQL functions in a Django project?

Tags: django, plpgsql

In a Django project, I am using several custom PL/pgSQL functions. So far I have used migrations to add these to the database. However, I think this is not the best way to do it, especially if you need to add some changes now and then. What do you consider as best way to oganize your database functions in a Django environment?

Maybe as fixtures? Maybe as custom handler to the post_sync signal?

Comment: I use migrations and think that is the best place for it. I precede each function with `CREATE OR REPLACE (...)`, so I can easily change it in a future migration if needed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I used to do as well. But always felt that fixing bugs and extending the function is a pain. I have to add the whole code again in a new migration and couldn't work on a file that is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Ok, but you can't change a PL/pgSQL function without copying the code, so I'm a little bit confused how do you exactly want to change/edit the function.

Comment: Sure, but in a migration I would be required to provide the "old" function in the `backward` migration and the new one (changed version) in the `forward` part, both I have to create/copy by hand. Therefore, it would be easier (I think) to have this function in a file and load it after each migration. Forward/Backward is taken care of by the version control, essentially. Using this way I would not need to copy the function code into a new file (like the migration), but would use---also for testing!---the file the function lives in anyway.